# Do we run out of questions or?

Tags: discussion, scope

Beer.sx is quite active in the first days of its closed beta. But now, there is no new question in the last 4 days, and there is very low activity on the existing questions.

I can say I am novice in beer topics, I try to answer if I can and I try to richen my answer using web so it may help more people and it would become more satisfactory. But beyond that, I do not have much to ask.

So I am trying to figure out the problem. Do we ask all that a community can ask? I guess not. Beer can not be so narrow to fit all in topics in 212 questions. So the problem must be somewhere else. Maybe, choosing what is on-topic and what is not cause this.

So what is the main reason of this low activity? How can we overcome this?

Comment: I'm of the opinion that the beer SE should be merged with all other beverage SE proposals (coffee, tea).

Comment: *All beverages* might be too wide, it can be narrowed to *alcohol beverages* too. Wine itself may produce quite a lot of questions alone, adding this to other alcohol beverages and local drinks will make the topic wide enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make things worse, low activity begets low activity.  Today we're showing fewer than 100 visits/day.  The obvious effect is that with lower activity people don't need to come around as much (nothing new to read/answer).  But there's a less-obvious effect, possibly more important than that: lower activity increases the perception that the site will close, and if the site is going to close there's not much incentive to work to improve it (effort spent on posts will be lost, at least for most of them -- nowhere to migrate).

So not only do we need to figure out how to increase activity, but we need to do it before too many potential contributors wander away.

If this site is to exist alongside Homebrewing, I wonder if we should broaden the scope to wine, cider, and mead.  Homebrewing is about *making* these beverages and maybe this site should be about *consuming* them -- all of them, not just beer.  (We would need to adjust the site's name in that case.)  Because this site was created it seems like there's a place for questions that are about beer but not about *making* beer; that's presumably just as true for wine et al.

(I was not involved in the Area 51 proposal for this site and I don't participate on Homebrewing.  I came here because, yum, beer.  If this discussion has already been held and resolved, I'm sorry and please point me to it.)

Comment: I am not certain about Area 51 Proposal  changes, but you are talking about  widening the concept and the name. A Mod may answer that, but everybody knows  here is about beer and just beer. Beside that, it can be a good idea since wine and liqueur have a wide content.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer lies in this question: [What kinds of questions will keep Beer.SE active? (Relax the culture against brands and regional questions.)](https://alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-kinds-of-questions-will-keep-beer-se-active-relax-the-culture-against-bra)

The problem is: what's left to ask?  I can no longer think of non-opinion-based questions to ask, and it seems most other people have run out too.  So, although beer is not a narrow topic, factual questions that don't fit under homebrewing.SE may be.

I think the best answer might be to try to encourage more regional answers (which we decided were allowed in the above linked question).  Unfortunately, we might not have the critical mass for that to work: if someone asks where to get beer X near Milwaukee, but no one from Milwaukee uses this site, it likely becomes a dead question.

Comment: Regional questions might not end up like that. The other seconario is, they will attract users to site. Because such questions have answers that are hard to find on internet. Also such questions might get answered in the future. That is a possibility and IMO, that can be tried.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This site is cool because I like beer, but it doesn't work. Especially with there being already a homebrew site where you basically ask almost any question you could ask here.